# Visual Studio 2017 and Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

After sincronize changes appears some files excluded in the project. How I can avoid it?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoJPf.png)

Answer (score 0):

All excluded files project you will find in .gitignore file. Please edit it.